# c++ vector object .erase

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have been struggling to put a vector object into a project im doing
I have read what little i could find about doing this and decided to give it a go.

```
      std::vector<BrickFalling> fell;
      BrickFalling *f1;
```

I created the vector. This next piece works fine until i get to the erase
section.

```
if(brickFall == true){

f1 = new BrickFalling;

f1->getBrickXY(brickfallx,brickfally);

fell.push_back(*f1);
brickFall = false;
}
// Now setup an iterator loop through the vector

vector<BrickFalling>::iterator it;

for( it = fell.begin(); it != fell.end(); ++it ) {

   // For each BrickFalling, print out their info

   it->printBrickFallingInfo(brick,window,deadBrick);

   //This is the part im doing wrong /////
   if(deadBrick == true)// if dead brick erase
   {
       BrickFalling[it].erase;//not sure what im supposed to be doing here
       deadBrick = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not look like a good place to use `new`. My money is on that object being leaked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer detailing the use of `remove_if` should be used whenever possible. If, however, your situations does not allow you to write your code using `remove_if`, which can happen in more complicated situations, you can use the following:

You can use `vector::erase` with an iterator to remove the element at that spot. The iterator used is then invalidated. `erase` returns a new iterator that points to the next element, so you can use that iterator to continue.

What you end up with is a loop like:

```
for( it = fell.begin(); it != fell.end(); /* iterator updated in loop */ )
{
     if (shouldDelete)
         it = fell.erase(it);
     else
         ++it;
}
```

Comment: `std::remove_if` is already made and tested. If code looks like this, it should be replaced with that and probably `erase` on the result.

Comment: That's a good point. Not all situations are neatly written as `remove_if` followed by `erase`, so for these (more exceptional) situations my code can be used.

Answer (score 4):

You can totally avoid the issue by using  `std::remove_if` along with `vector::erase`.

```
auto it = 
   std::remove_if(fell.begin(), fell.end(), [&](BrickFalling& b) 
              { bool deadBrick = false;      
                b.printBrickFallingInfo(brick,window,deadBrick);
                return deadBrick; });

   fell.erase(it, fell.end());
```

This avoids the hand-writing of the loop.

In general, you should strive to write erasure loops for sequence containers in this fashion.  The reason is that it is very easy to get into the "invalid iterator" scenario when writing the loop yourself, i.e. not remembering to reseat your looping iterator each time an erase is done.

The only issue with your code which I do not know about is the `printBrickFallingInfo` function.  If it `throws` an exception, you may introduce a bug during the erasure process.  In that case, you may want to protect the call with a `try/catch` block to ensure you don't leave the function block too early.

Edit:

As the comment stated, your `print...` function could be doing too much work just to determine if a brick is falling.  If you really are attempting to print stuff and do even more things that *may* cause some sort of side-effect, another approach similar in nature would be to use `std::stable_partition`.

With `std::stable_partition` you can "put on hold" the erasure and just move the elements to be erased at one position in the container (either at the beginning or at the end) *all without invalidating those items*.  That's the main difference -- with `std::stable_partition`, all you would be doing is move the items to be processed, but the items after movement are still valid.  Not so with `std::remove` and `std::remove_if` -- moved items are just invalid and any attempt to use those items as if they are still valid is undefined behavior.

```
auto it = 
   std::stable_partition(fell.begin(), fell.end(), [&](BrickFalling& b) 
              { bool deadBrick = false;      
                b.printBrickFallingInfo(brick,window,deadBrick);
                return deadBrick; });

   // if you need to do something with the moved items besides
   // erasing them, you can do so.  The moved items start from
   // fell.begin() up to the iterator it.
   //...
   //...
   // Now we erase the items since we're done with them
   fell.erase(fell.begin(), it);
```

The difference here is that the items we will *eventually* erase will lie to the left of the partitioning iterator `it`, so our `erase()` call will remove the items starting from the beginning.  In addition to that, the items are still perfectly valid entries, so you can work with them in any way you wish before you finally erase them.

Comment: Just want to add a small note that a function called `print...` seems to be changing `deadBrick`. It looks like it's doing too much and should be at least split up into `print...` and `isDeadBrick`.